# Bypass "Sign in with Apple"

Tags: ios, xcode

My current app has sign up with SNS feature but my server is not ready for Sign in with Apple feature yet. Now how can I bypass App Store rejection in review for not implementing Sign in with Apple. If I archive the app using Xcode 10, can I bypass the review?

Comment: There is no way to bypass that other than not adding other ins like google facebook

Comment: no! you con't. apple review process this is the highest priority.

Answer (score 0):

App Store doesn't care about what IDE you used to archive your binary. They will review your app thoroughly, anyway.

They still accept apps that don't have Sign In with Apple. But in future ( no one knows when) they will reject.

So, for now they will let your app in the App Store, but you should work on it and get it ready.

Comment: as of today, they reject if Sign in with Apple is not included.